# tool to find the routing distance between two latitude/longitude points using OSM data

Tags: pgrouting, distance, routing

I need a tool to find the distance between two points whose longitude and latitude are given. I am making an application so it will require bulk queries, so i cannot use google maps distance matrix API that could tell me the distance via road, airways or any other.
So I turned up to OSM data, i downloaded the OSM data and then pgrouting tool. But I am unable to find the distance via road between two points from this data stored in postgres table.

Any help regarding how to fetch this data from the postgresql db or any other resource you know that can accomplish my goal will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pgRouting requires each road entry to have a start and an end node id. If your dataset already contains this information, you can skip this step. Otherwise we will create the node ids now - http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/ credit to @underdark

Comment: CAn you project the point to the nearest line and use the projection for mapping?

Answer (score 6):

OSM has a page dedicated to routing, which is worth going over:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

There is a special tool for importing OSM data into a PGRouting system and generating the required structure:

https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting

Lastly, there is a workshop tutorial on getting routing working with OSM data here:

http://workshop.pgrouting.org/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GraphHopper](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/) for this task. Have a look into the [documentation](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/wiki) for more information.